# problem posting embeds in discord.net 2.0

Tags: discord.net

So I have been trying to figure this out but I can't find any sources on discord.net 2.0.0-beta which I am currently using.

My question is how to post an embed in the chat, I know how to build one and what the different things do but when I do the method I used in 1.0 it comes up with an error regarding not being able to convert Discord.EmbedBuilder to Discord.Embed

Any help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
        EmbedFooterBuilder efb = new EmbedFooterBuilder();
        EmbedFieldBuilder ef = new EmbedFieldBuilder();

            SocketGuild server = ((SocketGuildChannel)msg.Channel).Guild;

            //Incorrect use
            if (parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"**Correct Usage**: `{Syntax}`");
                return;
            }

        eb.Title = server.Name;
        eb.Description = "this is a really fancy description";

        await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed: eb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `Build()` method on the `EmbedBuilder` instance.

[There was an implicit conversion from EmbedBuilder -> Embed that was removed in the 2.0 development cycle.](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/pull/801)

Answer (score 0):

You also can

```cs
var embed = new EmbedBuilder();

embed.WithTitle("Normal title");
embed.WithDescription("So cute description");
embed.WithFooter("Wawwww i love stanley");
Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
```